# conditional probability of event sequence based on target goal

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I am trying to figure out the relative likelihood of 3 possible "targets" given a sequence of events. Let's say I want to assign likelihoods to three targets, A, B, and C, based on the occurrence of 3 possible events: a, b, c. Occurrence of "a" should increase the probability of target A, "b" should increase the probability of target B, and "c" should increase the probability of target C.

"bias" is a term that regulates the likelihood of a target based on an event occurring at the start of the sequence, set apriori to 0.60, i.e., if event "a" occurs first, then it is 60% likely that the goal is A. This term is mainly relevant for the initial event.

At the beginning, when no event has happened, i.e. t=0,

```
P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 0.33
```

At t=1, let's say event "a" happens first, which leads to increase in A's likelihood by a bias term:

```
P(A) = bias = 0.6
P(B) = (1-P(A))/2 = 0.2
P(C) = (1-P(C)/2) = 0.2
```

At t=2, event "b" happens. Now I want to figure out the probability of each target A, B, and C after "a" and "b" have happened. I was trying to figure out a Bayes version of this but I'm getting confused. Intuitively, the occurrence of "b" after "a" should increase the likelihood of target B and slightly reduce the likelihood of target A, and possibly not have any effect on the likelihood of target C.

$$
P( A | current = b, previous = a) = \frac{P(current = b| A, previous = a)P(A, previous = a)}{P(current = b, previous = a)}
$$

Events a, b, and c are equally likely at each step. Am I thinking about this correctly or do I need some additional information to compute these probabilities beyond what is specified above?

Comment: Could you explain how you know what these "bias term" values are?  That might help us figure out how to obtain enough information to answer your question, because currently it doesn't stipulate any probability model with sufficient clarity to be answerable.

Comment: Hi, I have added more info about this bias now, basically bias regulates how the first event is perceived, i.e., "a" occurring first means that 60% chance than A is the target. Let me know if this makes sense, thanks!